# Reviewing suggested edits: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When I logged in today, I found out that I had a review queue with a suggested edit for me to approve or reject.

I'm not sure how to do that. The first edit looked like this:

[image]

This looks to me like the edit just inserts random words.

I skipped it, but the next two were similarly nonsensical. So I suspect I'm not reading the right way. Or are there saboteurs at work?

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [review audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/214632).

Comment: Reject. If you run into that behavior again (or if you bother to check the user profile to see other suggested edits), flag one of the posts, and point out that the user (include a user link, of course) has been making these weird edits.

Comment: @Arthur: That makes more sense!

Comment: @Asaf: Actually, your comment [also has some merit](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/182588).

Comment: @Arthur: Thank you, that's a very plausible explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is, most likely, a review audit.  The *first* step in the process is to click "reject."  Then, one of two things happen, which determines the *next* step.

1. You get a message "you passed the audit!"  Move on and keep reviewing--there's nothing more to see here.
2. You advance to the next item to review or the end of the queue **without** receiving the "you passed!" message.  In this case, the edit was an actual attempt at defacement.  Click your browser's "back" button, copy the user link of the editor, and flag the post for moderator attention and explain what's happening.  (Include the user link.)

At the end, pat yourself on the back for making Math.SE a better place. `:)`